# Сравнение 3 столбцов в excel

Tags: excel, сравнение

как написать формулу в правилах условного форматирования:
необходимо сравнить 3 столбца: если столб.1 содержит значение столб.2, а значение столб.3 = x, то закрасить цветом совпадающие ячейки

Comment: У вас есть какие-то наработки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте формулу, для условного форматирования:

```
=И($A2=$B2;$C2=$H$1)
```

Будут выделены строки в которых значение столбца 1 равно столбцу 2, а значение столбца 3 равно контрольному значению

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Или так (обрезаются лишние вычисления): `=ЕСЛИ($A2=$B2;$C2=$H$1)`